# UK LLC dissolved but PAYE not closed - how to remedy?

Tags: united-kingdom, payroll-taxes

I used to have a UK LLC which I dissolved as it ceased trading. I believe I informed HMRC about this and submitted final accounts and a CT600.

However, I did not do anything about PAYE (I just stopped reporting it like I did before in Payroo) and that's bad because HRMC has been expecting GBP 16.67 every month for many months now and hit me with a GBP 254 bill.

What's the best way for me to inform HMRC that PAYE scheme is closed as the company is dissolved and to convince them to recalculate the PAYE bill they've hit me with?

Comment: I would probably just call their customer service line and ask them, it's quite a niche issue I would imagine!

Comment: Last few times I tried (admittedly, a year ago) they put me on hold for one hour, then the call dropped. But OK, I will try. The number is 0300 200 3200.

Comment: Call them first thing in the early morning. That is the best time to get things done. You have to inform them about PAYE, else they will keep on demanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called the help line. They instructed me to use their Basic PAYE Tools to do an earlier year update with ‘Final submission because scheme ceased’ box ticked, roughly as per https://www.gov.uk/stop-employing-staff .